# Pushing a new ViewController from a ViewController that is embedded in a TabBarController and NavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tab bar controller that has a navigation controller embedded and then a view controller from there. In that view controller I have a table and I'm trying to display a new view controller when the user selects a row.

I'm trying to build a contacts page (bringing in iOS contact information) and displaying it.

Here is what the StoryBoard looks like

[image]

On cell select I want it to move to the Single Contact view.
The code that pulls in the contacts to show on the table works just fine. Here is the PublicContactsViewController class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
#import "SingleContactViewController.h"
#import "Person.h" 

@interface PublicContactsViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet ADBannerView *banner;

@end
```

---

```
#import "PublicContactsViewController.h"

@interface PublicContactsViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tableData;
@end

@implementation PublicContactsViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _banner.delegate = self;
 //   self.title = @"Public Contacts";
    self.tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self getPersonOutOfAddressBook];

}

#pragma mark - Address Book Methods

- (void)getPersonOutOfAddressBook
{
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;

    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);
    if (addressBook != nil){
        NSLog(@"getPersonOutOfAddressBook - addressBook successfull!.");

        NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
        NSUInteger i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < [allContacts count]; i++){
            Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];

            ABRecordRef contactPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];
            NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
            NSString *lastName =  (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
            NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName, lastName];

            person.firstName = firstName;
            person.lastName = lastName;
            person.fullName = fullName;

            //email
            ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson,
                                                       kABPersonEmailProperty);
            NSUInteger j = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(emails); j++){
                NSString *email = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, j);
                if (j == 0){
                    person.homeEmail = email;                 
                    NSLog(@"person.homeEmail = %@ ", person.homeEmail);                 
                }                              
                else if (j==1)                     
                    person.workEmail = email;
                    NSLog(@"person.workEmail = %@ ", person.workEmail);
            }           

            [self.tableData addObject:person];         
        }     
    }          

    CFRelease(addressBook); 
}


#pragma mark - Table View Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Identifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    Person *person = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = person.fullName;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Cell was clicked");
    Person *person = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Person selected: %@",person);
    SingleContactViewController *singleContactViewController = [[SingleContactViewController alloc] initWithPerson:person];
    NSLog(@"created singlecontactviewcontroller");

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:singleContactViewController animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    // Gets called when iAds is loaded.
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    // Set iAd to visible, creates nice fade-in effect
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Gets called when iAds can't be loaded (no internet connection).
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    // Set iAd to visible, creates nice fade-in effect
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}



@end
```

---

**Here is the error I am receiving when I click on a cell**

```
2013-12-05 07:25:35.186 ConfidentialContacts[21902:70b] Cell was clicked
2013-12-05 07:25:35.187 ConfidentialContacts[21902:70b] Person selected: <Person: 0xad670c0>
2013-12-05 07:25:35.187 ConfidentialContacts[21902:70b] created singlecontactviewcontroller
2013-12-05 07:25:35.225 ConfidentialContacts[21902:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/david/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/7DCB2344-3497-4CAF-BA47-8E80E6D1FBB6/CustomContacts> (loaded)' with name 'SingleContactViewController''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your using storyboard segue then better use `prepareForSegue:` method and pass the person object.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Cell was clicked");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];

}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourSegueIdentifier" ]) {

         NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
         Person *person = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         NSLog(@"Person selected: %@", person);
         SingleContactViewController *singleContactViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
         singleContactViewController.person = person; // create person object as a property in SingleContactViewController and assign the person object.
    NSLog(@"created singlecontactviewcontroller");

   } 

}
```

Comment: So I need to provide a segue in the storyboard? From the the ViewController to the destination view controller?

Comment: As per your storyboard image, you have already created the segue, just give it the identifier name and use above code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can push a new controller onto an existing one. Just segue to the new view. This will push the view onto the viewController's stack.